# Let $R$ a ring and $M$ be an $R-$module freely generated by a set $X$, and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. Show that $Y$ freely generates $RY$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated, free-modules

I have tried the following way:
I want to show that $RY=L_R(Y)$, then be $rz\in  RY$ where $r\in  R$ and $z\in Y$, as $Y\subseteq X\subseteq M$ and $M=L_R(X)$ then $z= \sum_{i=1}^{n}r_ib_i$ where $X=\left \{ b_1,b_2,...,b_n\right \}$ so $rz=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(rr_i)b_i$. 
But I need is that every $b_i\in Y$ and I do not know how to do this.

Comment: You should define your notation for us. I would read $RY$ as the $R$-span of $Y$, in which case I would write $M=RX$ and insist the entire thing is obvious.

Comment: Ok, $R$ is a ring

Comment: Your definition of $RY$ seems to be wrong. I get that $R$ is a ring, that's not the problem.

Comment: This exercise is taken from the book "rings, modules and linear algebra" by hawkes and there do not specify much, I think that is the problem, I also know very well that it is RY.

Comment: You say that elements of $RY$ are of the form $rz$ for $r\in R$ and $z\in Y$. This is not right.

Comment: Then what is $RY$?

Comment: The only sensible definition is $$RY=\left\{z\in M\mid z=\sum_i r_iy_i\mid r_i\in R, y_i\in Y\right\}.$$

Comment: But if so defined exercise would be simpler, right?

Comment: That's what I suggested in my first comment.